# ASP.NET Custom Localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, resourceproviderfactory

I've done quite a bit of research and I'm not sure how I should proceed with this.

Usual localization would change only when the language changes, so Hello for french would be Bonjour but my application needs to have special keywords for for certain users so UserX might say "Hello" needs to be "Allo".

I would like to have resource key with **IdentityName_resourceKey** and if this key is present take it otherwize fall back to **resourceKey**.

I'm thinking I need a custom ResourceProvider but my implementation is a simple if statement so I would not want to write a complete resource provider.

I wrote a extension of DisplayName attribute which works fine but this is not very good as I will need one of those for every data annotation attributes and this would not work if I use resources directly in pages or controllers...

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    private readonly PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;

    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey, Type resourceType) : base(resourceKey)
    {
        var clientName = CustomMembership.Instance.CurrentUser.Client.Name;

        _propertyInfo = resourceType.GetProperty(clientName + "_" + base.DisplayName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public) 
                            ?? resourceType.GetProperty(base.DisplayName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_propertyInfo == null)
            {
                return base.DisplayName;
            }

            return (string) _propertyInfo.GetValue(_propertyInfo.DeclaringType, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for the best way to implement this with the least amount of code..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way, Data Annotations is your answer!

this is just a sample, you need go more deeper with System.Globalization.CultureInfo and Data Annotations (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)

you can define your model class like this (assuming we have a resource file named CustomResourceValues with a value "strHello")

```
public class SomeObject(){

    <Display(Name:="strHello", ResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.CustomResourceValues))>
    public string HelloMessage{ get; set; }

}
```

so, in our view the work must do it by the htmlhelper (assuming razor like render engine and the model is type of "SomeObject")

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.HelloMessage)
```

basic info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.resourcetype(v=vs.95).aspx